# Responsive non-linear section transition (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-grid

I'm searching for an elegant way to make non-horizontal section transition in my HTML (Bootstrap) page.

[image: Here is what I mean]

It should work on mobile and also with video- or parallax backgrounds.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two approaches avaiable:

- It's a good idea to use plain PNG images, that you explicit set the height and where you wanna "crop" the block, but this approach make take longer to load, because you have to load all the PNGs images. Like this:`<div style="height: 200px; overflow: auto; background-image: your-image.png"></div>`
- You can use CSS clip-path  property combined with a polygon, which in fact is a little more difficult because you have to specify all the points in the polygon you wanna make. A hexagon example: `clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 25%);` You can se more about clip-path here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

Finally I would choose the first approach. because is more scalable and easier to implement, in the future if you want to change the shape, just redraw it in some software of you choice, on the other hand with clip-path you would have to rethink all the points and where to put them.

Comment: Thank you for your approaches I think I will try the first one.

How would the markup look with boostrap? Where would you put the backgroundimages (row)?
`<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" id="section_1">
            <div class="col-md-12"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="section_2">
            <div class="col-md-12"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="section_3"></div>
    </div>
</body>`

Comment: I would put them inside the div with col, like this `<body> <div class="container"> <div class="row" id="section_1"> <div class="col-md-12"><div style="height: 200px; overflow: auto; background-image: your-image.png"></div> </div> </div> </body>`, of course it's a good practice to create a class for each styling you're using, so instead of having 'style=...", create a class and you that class